# code pipeline abort the approval stage after 30 mins

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

abort a build if its not approved for 30 mins in code pipeline, abort manual approval stage if its not done for 30 mins

1. the default waiting time is 7 days I need to reduce it
2. decrease the same to 30 mins

Answer (score 0):

CodePipeline's manual approval waiting time isn't configurable.